# How do you open a file on windows for python? having unexpected issues

Tags: python, syntax, permissions, directory

I want to read a text file on windows from python. I've done this on a mac terminal a million times but have just started using windows. First thing is to open the file:

```
file = open("C:\users\lbryan05\documents\Training\python\Lynda\ch 2\words.txt",       'r')
```

, which gives the syntax error:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape

I gathered something weird is happening with \u so I tried putting an r in front of the path to double up all the backslashes:

```
file = open(r"C:\users\lbryan05\documents\Training\python\Lynda\ch 2\words.txt",       'r')
```

So from this I get that 'no such directory exists'. So I gather windows is stupid and hides file extensions so I just need to emit words.txt. After doing that I am surprised by the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "path".

, which just makes no sense to me as to why I wouldn't have permission to the file because I can certainly access it. 
I'm executing python through windows powershell (and sublime).

Comment: You get "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "path"." error when you try to open a directory instead of a file. Your second command should work. Please check if you have the file in that location.

Comment: You can escape \ easily adding a second backslash. `something\\user` is equal to `something\user` but escaped so you don't get unicode errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too big I suggest to store the file on that variable, then do the desired changes on python, and then save the entire file with the editted data, using 'w' parameter into the file.

Try this:

```
# Open file to read it, and store it in a var.
with open("C:\\users\\lbryan05\\documents\\Training\\python\\Lynda\\ch 2\\words.txt", 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
# Do something with that var, manipulate it like you want
file_content = file_content + "test"
# Open file to write on it, and write your manipulated var.
with open("C:\\users\\lbryan05\\documents\\Training\\python\\Lynda\\ch 2\\words.txt", 'w') as w:
    w.write(file_content)
```